# How do I move an existing question I wrote from Stack Overflow to Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, migration

Is there an easy way to move an existing question I wrote from Stack Overflow to Server Fault without reposting the question on Server Fault?

Comment: Link the question? If it's appropriate, one of the many moderators here can insta-migrate it for you.

Comment: Note, if it's older than 60 days, then we can't move it, the system prevents us.  So get that flag in there quick (of course, we have to find it in the hundreds of flags).  If you have a specific question, probably better to post the link here.

Comment: I've looked at your questions and don't see any that would be a better fit for SF than SO. Which one are you talking about ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag the question for "moderator attention" and state your request.

If you have enough reputation you can cast a close vote as "off-topic," but that needs 5 votes to get it closed and it is not guaranteed to be migrated to the other site.

[image: vote-to-close]

Comment: I have 54 reputation over there, where is that flag ?

Comment: You only need [15 rep points](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) to flag. Follow the link to see how.

Comment: Found the the flag, thanks!

Comment: Since the UTC evening of 2012-11-30 SF has been removed from the SO default migration list.

Comment: @Iain: Thanks for the pointer. Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to flag the question to allow a moderator to migrate the question.

Note that the guidelines for what questions are migrated are rather strict.  It's important that the question not only follow all of the rules for a question on the target site, but that it be a good question the target site would really *want*.  Effort is made to not migrate questions that will just be closed or need further editing.

Even moderators can't migrate questions that are more than 60 days old.